# Rails 3 syntax error in development when line is split into multiple lines in controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, passenger

When I was developing my project on my local file I had this line in code which worked correctly:

```
@json = Location.qty_of_deliv_from(params[:from_rc])
  .qty_of_deliv_to(params[:to_rc])
```

When I deployd with passenger I get a syntax error on this line which goes avay if I have all the code in the same line:

```
@json = Location.qty_of_deliv_from(params[:from_rc]).qty_of_deliv_to(params[:to_rc])
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: What's the syntax error you get specifically? I think it's probably a fluke that the split line works at all. If you entered that code in the console with a split line, it certainly wouldn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps your server's ruby version is different and parses differently?

In any case, in Ruby, when writing multiline code you typically want to make sure your lines to be wrapped are syntactically incomplete, so as not to confuse the parser, e.g. by using a hanging dot, instead.

```
Location.qty_of_deliv_from(params[:form_rc]).
  qty_of_deliv_to(params[:to_rc])
```

Or you can use the backslash to escape the new line:

```
Location.qty_of_deliv_from(params[:form_rc]) \
  .qty_of_deliv_to(params[:to_rc])
```

Comment: Correct! A hanging dot indicates the method chain continues on the next line in all the Ruby versions I've used. By putting it on the next line, it's ambiguous what precisely it's continuing and so the parser throws an error.